# How to add open graph meta tags to WordPress wp-login page?

Tags: wordpress

I've added open graph meta tags to my site using Yoast and it works with the exception of the login page (wp-login). How do I add the tags to the wp-login page too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta tags are not usually included in the login page for security reasons, even so if you want to do that, you can do it by creating a custom action hook.

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'custom_no_robots', 9);

function custom_no_robots() {
    remove_action( 'login_head', 'wp_no_robots' );
    echo "[HERE]"; // [Here] you can call your open graph locale presentation, or if you prefer on echo you can put directly your <meta...
}
```